# Wiring and unwiring events in C# with arguments

Tags: c#, events

i am trying to make use of events in C#. I am really new to events. Following is my code.

```
     public void GetVoltage(Object objName, Object objCcaVar)
{
  DynamicSystemVariable mysys = new DynamicSystemVariable("VTS::M9_Ch3", "AvgVoltage");
  mysys.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => mysys_ValueChanged(sender, e, ""); ;

}


void mysys_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e,String name)
{       
    DynamicSystemVariable mysys = (DynamicSystemVariable)sender;
    Output.WriteLine(mysys.GetValue().ToString());
    Output.WriteLine("System Variable Changed");
    if (_unwireEvent)
        mysys.ValueChanged -= mysys_ValueChanged;
}
```

It gives me following error on the line where i am unwiring it. 
No overload for 'mysys_ValueChanged' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

I will appreciate if somebody can help me out.

Thanks 
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't register `mysys_ValueChanged`. You registered an anonymous method.

You have to change your code to:

```
public void GetVoltage(Object objName, Object objCcaVar)
{
  DynamicSystemVariable mysys = new DynamicSystemVariable("VTS::M9_Ch3", "AvgVoltage");
  mysys.ValueChanged += this.OnEvent;

}

private void OnEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  mysys_ValueChanged(sender, e, "");
}

void mysys_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e,String name)
{       
    DynamicSystemVariable mysys = (DynamicSystemVariable)sender;
    Output.WriteLine(mysys.GetValue().ToString());
    Output.WriteLine("System Variable Changed");
    if (_unwireEvent)
        mysys.ValueChanged -= OnEvent;  // Unregister what you've registered.
}
```

**EDIT**

Having new input it could be solved that way:

```
public void GetVoltage(Object objName, Object objCcaVar)
{
  DynamicSystemVariable mysys = new DynamicSystemVariable("VTS::M9_Ch3", "AvgVoltage");

  EventHandler<EventArgs> handler = null;
  handler = (s, e) => mysys_ValueChanged(s, e, "", handler);

  mysys.ValueChanged += handler;   
}

void mysys_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, String name, EventHandler<EventArgs> handler)
{       
    DynamicSystemVariable mysys = (DynamicSystemVariable)sender;
    Output.WriteLine(mysys.GetValue().ToString());
    Output.WriteLine("System Variable Changed");
    if (_unwireEvent)
        mysys.ValueChanged -= handler;  // Unregister what you've registered.
}
```

I haven't tried it but I think this could work - but in my opinion it's hacked.

Comment: Thanks Vera for your reply. it works. But i think i made mistake while asking question. Actually i need to pass parameter objCcaVar that i am receiving in GetVoltage function. How can i pass that parameter to mysys_ValueChanged.

Comment: Oh. That's tricky. You can store it in a private member but the next call of `GetVoltage` will override it. If you need multiple calles of `GetVoltage` without overriding it you've to create a new class instance that contains the event handler (`mysys_ValueChanged`) and takes the value in constructor. Then you register the event handler method of this class. That's the only way if you need to unregister the handler. If you don't need unregistering the best way would be using a lambda.

Comment: Oh you can hack a little bit if you store the lambda to an local variable and pass it to the event handler. The event handler can unregister it.

Comment: Vera, how do i store lambda to an local variable. Can you please write it down if its quick for you. I think i tried it but maybe could not get it right.

Comment: i tried the edit you just posted. It gives me compile error at line or wiring and unwiring Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler<System.EventArgs>

Comment: Change `EventHandler` to `EventHandler<EventArgs>`. I changed the sample.

Comment: Vera, you know what you are genius. It worked. I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sending `name` as a seperate parameter, create a new class deriving from `EventArgs` and add `name` parameter to this class as a property. Something like;

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Name {get; private set;}
    public MyEventArgs(EventArg e, string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

mysys.ValueChanged += mysys_ValueChanged(sender, new MyEventArgs("some name"));
```

Also do not forget to change the signiture of `mysys_ValueChanged`.

Note that this is just a workaround, and proper way is defining a new delegate which uses `MyEventArgs` and using a seperate handling method instead of an inline method.

Comment: Maybe this will compile but it will not work because `mysys_ValueChanged` unregisters itself but registered is an anonymous method.

Comment: Thanks Daryal. It looks good solution. It teaches me atleast how to pass your own EventArgs class. Actually class that throws event is not written by me its part of framework that i use.